# Windows Batch If Block Syntax

Tags: windows, batch-file

I really can't find what's the problem with the syntax of this script

There's something wrong with the if blocks but I can't see what is the issue.

```
@ECHO off

set PROJECT=C:/ws/UI/Trunky/plugins/.
set EXE=grails
set MVN=mvn
set DEP=--refresh-dependencies
set CLEAN=clean
set ASSET=ProcessAssets -Dgrails.env=production -DRESOURCE_PATH=./assets
set TEST=test-app unit: --non-interactive
set FIXJS=-s ./hudson-config/settings.xml package
set INPUT="%1"

IF "%1" == "-dep"(
    ECHO %EXE% %DEP%
    ECHO "Refreshing dependencies."
) IF "%1" == "-clean"(
    ECHO %EXE% %CLEAN%
    ECHO "Cleaning up."
)IF "%1" == "-asset"(
    ECHO %EXE% %ASSET%
    ECHO "Processing assets."
)IF "%1" == "-test"(
    ECHO %EXE% %TEST%
    ECHO "Running Groovy tests."
)IF "%1" == "-fixjs"(
    ECHO %MVN% %FIXJS%
    ECHO "Copying JS, Running Jasmine and performing coverage report."
)IF "%1" == "-lazy"(
     ECHO rmdir /s /q "%PROJECT%"
     ECHO %EXE% %DEP%
     ECHO %EXE% %CLEAN%
     ECHO %EXE% %ASSET%
     ECHO %MVN% %FIXJS%
)

ECHO "Done. Have a great day!"
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing? I don't see anything wrong with the IF blocks, you're opening and closing all of them properly. Edit your post and show the output you're getting

Answer (score 7):

'Start each IF on its own line, leave a space before the opening parenthesis.

The reason that the above fixes the problem is that .cmd files expect one command per line, and the closing parenthesis "ends" the statement.  Thus, the additional IF following the closing parenthesis begins another, unexpected, command on the same line.

The construct

```
if "%1" == "somestring" (
echo "%1"
)
```

is effectively interpreted as one line, with the closing parenthesis and carriage return ending the line and the 'if'.

This makes for one "tricky" 'if' construct

```
if "%1" == "somestring" (
echo "%1"
) else (
echo "Not %1"
)
```

Since 'else' is part of the 'if' syntax the 'else' must be included on the same line as the closing parenthesis to "continue" the 'if' statement.

The space is required before the opening parenthesis as a simple syntax requirement.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, and what you say about the deleting method?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked.  I don't know what "deleting method" you're talking about, sorry.  Could you be a little more clear?

Comment: @james that's valid for a comment but not for making an answer, please add more info.

Comment: @Electro Hacker - Heh.  You commented whilst I was expanding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is right - here is a visual example using your code.

```
@ECHO off

set PROJECT=C:/ws/UI/Trunky/plugins/.
set EXE=grails
set MVN=mvn
set DEP=--refresh-dependencies
set CLEAN=clean
set ASSET=ProcessAssets -Dgrails.env=production -DRESOURCE_PATH=./assets
set TEST=test-app unit: --non-interactive
set FIXJS=-s ./hudson-config/settings.xml package
set INPUT="%1"

IF "%1" == "-dep" (
    ECHO %EXE% %DEP%
    ECHO "Refreshing dependencies."
) 

IF "%1" == "-clean" (
    ECHO %EXE% %CLEAN%
    ECHO "Cleaning up."
)

IF "%1" == "-asset" (
    ECHO %EXE% %ASSET%
    ECHO "Processing assets."
)

IF "%1" == "-test" (
    ECHO %EXE% %TEST%
    ECHO "Running Groovy tests."
)

IF "%1" == "-fixjs" (
    ECHO %MVN% %FIXJS%
    ECHO "Copying JS, Running Jasmine and performing coverage report."
)

IF "%1" == "-lazy" (
     ECHO rmdir /s /q "%PROJECT%"
     ECHO %EXE% %DEP%
     ECHO %EXE% %CLEAN%
     ECHO %EXE% %ASSET%
     ECHO %MVN% %FIXJS%
)

ECHO "Done. Have a great day!"
```